# Redshift Varchar Maximum limit reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, varchar

I have a long field in a .csv file **'field_x'** and I have set the column size in the table DDL to VARCHAR(65535). When I try and run the COPY command to copy from the .csv file into the table, I receive the error **'String length exceeds DDL length'**.

How do I deal with this error as I have already set the varchar size to max? Does anyone have any experience dealing with the same?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your use-case you might be better off using the super data type https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html